# Вывод столбца который не содержится ни в статистической функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть запрос с подзапросом, в котором 4 столбца - цена, имя продукта, год и месяц продажи. В подзапросе мы получаем общее кол-во продаж всех товаров за каждый месяц каждого года `SUM(Quantity)`. В самом запросе - максимальное кол-во продаж одного товара в каждом месяце каждого года `MAX(x.Quantity)`. Есть проблема с выводом столбца с именем - при вводе "NAME" в `SELECT` основного запроса, SQL выдаёт ошибку

> Столбец "x.NAME" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в статистической функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.

Если ввести `NAME` в `GROUP BY`, запрос выдаёт тоже самое, что и подзапрос.
Помогите пожалуйста хотя бы советом новичку, не знаю как исправить данную ошибку. В приложенных файлах скриншот с выводом запроса и подзапроса, структура БД и сама БД в архиве.

Сам код:

```
USE Northwind
SELECT 
  MAX(x.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
  [YEAR], [MONTH] 
  FROM 
      (SELECT 
        SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
        YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR], 
        MONTH(OrderDate) AS [MONTH], 
        Products.ProductName AS NAME 
      FROM Products
      JOIN [ORDER Details] ON Products.ProductID = [ORDER Details].ProductID
      JOIN Orders ON [ORDER Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID 
      GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate), Products.ProductName) x
GROUP BY [YEAR], [MONTH]ORDER BY [YEAR], [MONTH]
```

[image: Вывод запроса и подзапроса]

[Структура БД](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dlUp.jpg)
 [БД в архиве](http://rgho.st/82MsDMqtS)

Comment: В поле Name должно выводиться наименование товара, продажи которого в этом месяце максимальны? Т.е. Вы хотите в каждом месяце выбрать товар, которого продалось больше всего?

Comment: Да, мне нужно получить наименование товара, продажи которого максимальны за каждый месяц каждого года. Учитывая при этом, что один и тот же товар продавался несколько раз за месяц, поэтому надо считать его(SUM(Quantity)) и делать группировку по году и месяцу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1 (немного переработанный ответ @msi):

```
with cte as
(SELECT 
  SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
  YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR], 
  MONTH(OrderDate) AS [MONTH], 
  Products.ProductName AS NAME FROM Products
JOIN [ORDER Details] ON Products.ProductID = [ORDER Details].ProductID
JOIN Orders ON [ORDER Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID 
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate), Products.ProductName)
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE Quantity=
(
  SELECT TOP 1 Quantity 
  FROM cte c 
  WHERE c.YEAR=cte.YEAR AND 
        c.MONTH=cte.MONTH 
  ORDER BY Quantity desc)
```

Выдаст несколько записей, если какие-то товары продавались одинаково.

Вариант 2 - с использованием ранжирования:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY 
        YEAR(orderdate), 
        MONTH(orderdate) 
     ORDER BY SUM(quantity) desc
    ) ord,
  SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
  YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR], 
  MONTH(OrderDate) AS [MONTH], 
  Products.ProductName AS NAME FROM Products
JOIN [ORDER Details] ON Products.ProductID = [ORDER Details].ProductID
JOIN Orders ON [ORDER Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate), Products.ProductName)
SELECT quantity, year, MONTH, NAME FROM cte WHERE ord=1 ORDER BY year, month
```

Всегда выдаст одну запись за месяц.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, что это SQL Server версии >=2005

```
with cte as
(SELECT 
  SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
  YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR], 
  MONTH(OrderDate) AS [MONTH], 
  Products.ProductName AS NAME FROM Products
JOIN [ORDER Details] ON Products.ProductID = [ORDER Details].ProductID
JOIN Orders ON [ORDER Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID 
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate), Products.ProductName)

select cte.* from cte join(
SELECT 
  MAX(x.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
  [YEAR], [MONTH] FROM cte
GROUP BY [YEAR], [MONTH]
) x on cte.quantity=x.quantity and cte.year=x.year and cte.month=x.month
```

Comment: "Предложение ORDER BY не допускается в представлениях, встроенных функциях, производных таблицах, вложенных запросах и обобщенных табличных выражениях, если не указано TOP или FOR XML"

Comment: Спасибо, измененная версия заработала! Только почему то столбцы дублируются - https://puu.sh/s98bt/6dca2815d3.png

Comment: столбцы дублируются, потому что `select *`. Поставьте алиас перед `*` - перестанут дублироваться.

Comment: Анон, внес исправления.